# set the actionBar tab's icon and text vertical to each other

Tags: android

```
Tab footballTab = actionBar.newTab();
footballTab.setText("Football");
footballTab.setIcon(android.R.drawable.btn_radio); //whatever
footballTab.setTabListener(this);

Tab basketBallTab = actionBar.newTab();
basketBallTab.setText("Basketball");
basketBallTab.setIcon(android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_off); //whatever
basketBallTab.setTabListener(this);

Tab tennisTab = actionBar.newTab();
tennisTab.setText("Tennis");
tennisTab.setIcon(android.R.drawable.btn_minus); //whatever
tennisTab.setTabListener(this);

actionBar.addTab(footballTab, false);
actionBar.addTab(basketBallTab, true); 
actionBar.addTab(tennisTab, false);
```

The result shows the icon and the text next to each other in a horizontal manner.

Is there a way I can show the icon and set the text below it ?

Moreover, is it possible to pass in custom views for the tab icon ?